# Generate pdf of chart obtained through chart.js in django

Tags: django, python-3.6

I want generate pdf of a template containing chart generated through chart.js and also table ,I have used reportlab but I neither get chart generated through chart.js nor css is applied over the table in django ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for these things and for converting dynamics chart into pdf you should always consider some stable library which supports different type of chart and wkhtmltopdf is good in that. It is easy to work with wkhtmltopdf in your Django app.